# Mysql Group By and ABS function Stack

Tags: mysql

I have sql code like this, when I execute the code with `GROUP BY` it just shows record number one and it doesn't use the `ABS`  function. Anyone can help me please?

```
SELECT *, `tblLifeAgency`.`AgencyName`, `mlp`.`Basic40`, `mlp`.`ADB40`, `mlp`.`CiAccel40`, `mlp`.`Basic50`, `mlp`.`ADB50`, `mlp`.`CiAccel50`, `mlp`.`Basic60`, `mlp`.`ADB60`, `mlp`.`CiAccel60`
FROM (`tblPackage`)
INNER JOIN `tblMatrixLifePackage` mlp ON `mlp`.`PackageID` = `tblPackage`.`PackageID`
INNER JOIN `tblCompany` ON `tblPackage`.`CompanyID` = `tblCompany`.`CompanyID`
INNER JOIN `tblLifeAgency` ON `tblLifeAgency`.`CompanyID` = `tblCompany`.`CompanyID`
AND `tblPackage`.`IsActive` =  '1'
WHERE `tblPackage`.`PackageType` =  '2'
GROUP BY tblPackage.CompanyID
ORDER BY abs(tblPackage.TotalPremi - 250000)
```

Comment: What are your expected inputs and outputs.  `GROUP BY` by definition will return one record for each group.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` groups your records. If you have record values, you have to decides which result to show as a summary for a line. For example, you can take all values in one group as positive (`ABS`) and sum them (`SUM`). Then try converting this pattern into your case (to understand better):

```
SELECT 
  `group`, 
  ABS(
    SUM(`value`)) AS `sum`
FROM my_table
GROUP BY `group`
```